# Problem downloading a 25MB file - the 8MB file downloads without problem (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, download

I have two files at the same location but the big one, when is about to finish download, gives an error (both in IE and Firefox).

I use the following code:

```
public static void DownloadZipFile (string filename, bool notifyMe)
{
    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
    HttpServerUtility server = context.Server;
    bool ok = false;
    try
    {
        string file = string.Format ("~/contents/licensing/members/downloads/{0}", filename);
        string server_file = server.MapPath (file);

        HttpResponse response = context.Response;
        //response.BufferOutput = false;
        response.ContentType = "application/zip";
        string value = string.Format ("attachment; filename={0}", filename);
        response.AppendHeader ("Content-Disposition", value);
        FileInfo f = new FileInfo (server_file);
        long size = f.Length;
        response.TransmitFile (server_file, 0, size);
        response.Flush ();
        ok = true;
        response.End ();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Utilities.Log (ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (ok && notifyMe)
            NotifyDownload (filename);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: After you get the size, add `response.AddHeader("Content-Length",size.ToString());` I've had similar problems with clients wanting "all the records on one page" and that being 70,000 records on an application written without any lazyloading. :(  iirc, the cap was 8MB.

Comment: Jim: +1 because what you proposed solved the problem I had. Now I can download the 25MB files. If you like, post the comment as answer. I know this is b...hit, but I have to select an answer. Or don't I. Anyway, never mind. Do as you wish. Thank you.

Comment: Well, the error came back... It drives me crazy!!! Sometimes I can download the file, and sometimes I can't! Before Jim's advice I couldn't at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to add the line:

```
response.AddHeader("Content-Length",size.ToString());
```

before the call to TransmitFile ().
The credits go to Jim Schubert (see his comment above).

Answer (score 0):

Response.End() calls Response.Flush().  Try removing the Flush call.

Comment: I did it on purpose; I wanted to set the "ok" flag to true before "response" go away, and after flushing contents. Anyway, this does not solve the problem. Jim above made a suggestion that helped. However, thank you for the comment.